# "Its" or "it’s" in "Getting Over It's IMPOSSIBLE PHYSICS!"

Tags: orthography, contractions, titles

While browsing through YouTube, I came across a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kj0NytW5Zbw) titled 
“Getting Over It's IMPOSSIBLE PHYSICS!” which references to a new game titled

> “Getting Over It with Bennett Foddy”.

My question is, is the use of the apostrophe in the video title correct? Should it be “Its” or “It’s” and why?

Comment: The video's title seems a play on words of the game it examines, which is called *Getting Over It*; the title adds *'s* to *it* to begin the next clause, *it's impossible physics*. Thus the same word *it* functions as the end of the first clause and the beginning of the next.

Comment: @Clare There's only one correct parse, though it's certainly a garden path construction. _Getting Over It_'s impossible physics = The impossible physics of _Getting Over It_.

Comment: @Clare You're saying that Getting Over It's impossible physics (note the demarcation of the 3-word proper noun by initial capitals) may be read as 'Getting over the fact that it is impossible physics'? And I'm sorry you feel it necessary to be rude.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Edwin, both in terms of the clearly-intended reading and Clare's apparent rudeness.  That said, Edwin, never engage in apologizing for another person's misbehavior--it's a passive-aggressive tactic that actually casts you in a poor light yourself, at least in front of anyone whose opinion you'd care about.  Maintain the high ground.

Comment: How is what Edwin says an "opinion" that one has to be "inclined to agree with"? What he states is an obvious fact. What Clare says is utter nonsense that beggars belief. Have we entered Bizarro World? I've not gotten the memo, guys.

Comment: @Edwin assumes that the title must be parsed according to standard grammatical rules; yet titles on social media are not always meant to be so parsed; social media are where both creativity and ignorance can be found. I chose to find creativity. Edwin (and it appears others) chose to interpret the title in another way. But this doesn't mean that the title *must* be so interpreted; it was this insistence that there is only one approach to the interpretation of the title that I found dogmatic and "an opinion", and being told this as rather heavy handed.

Comment: @Clare 'Edwin assumes that the title must be parsed according to standard grammatical rules; yet titles on social media are not always meant to be so parsed'. In that case, such queries should be immediately close-voted on a site devoted to standard rather than arbitrary usage. Even song lyrics have long been off-topic on ELU for this reason.

Comment: @Edwin then now what to do with the question? For, per standard grammar,   it seems an ELL-ish query.

Comment: I have close-voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has been downvoted and may not end up surviving, but I think it's actually a valid question to raise.

As discussed by others in the comments below your question, the issue here is one of poor choices of formatting or sentence structure, which makes it much more difficult to see the intended reading.

YouTube doesn't allow for italics in the headings/titles over its videos, which means one cannot italicize the game's title.  With italics, it becomes somewhat clearer:

> ***Getting Over It*'s IMPOSSIBLE PHYSICS**

It might have been clearer if the person titling the video had resorted to quotes or perhaps re-wording the title to make the game's title more distinct in the absence of italics, e.g.:

> **THE IMPOSSIBLE PHYSICS OF Getting Over It**

In short, though, I would say that I think the "***'s***" the author chose to use is indeed correct, but they *really* should have taken steps to make their intentions much clearer.

Comment: No need to reword, they could have simply put the title in quotation marks, as is indeed quite customary with all kinds of titles in all kinds of situations in all kinds of languages. These are always available, even when italics are not. But yeah, the basic construction is just that of *The queen of England's impossible crown*, or *That man I saw yesterday's impossible car*, or *The girl next door's impossible boobs*.

Comment: Indeed. My thinking is that people might be reluctant use _both_ quotation marks around the noun cluster that is the game title _and_ a possessive apostrophe that follows the quoted cluster, simply because there's an awkwardness in putting the two types of mark together: _"Quoted Thing"'s Thing._ In American English, one might move the _'s_ inside the quotes, as is a common rule for punctuation in style guides, but I consider that rule wrong-headed to begin with and I'd be very reluctant to suggest it. (An element not present in the _quoted_ text should never be between the _quotes_.)